# Can I jump updates / versions in CyanogenMod like from 10.0.0 to 10.1.2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates

When I'm installing updates through the built-in app in CyanogenMod, do I need to install all the previous (stable) versions before installing the last one? Or does the last package contain everything between the running version and the last one? ( I'm only interested in stable releases. Say I'm running CM 10.0.0. If I want to install 10.1.2, do I have to install 10.1.0 and 10.1.1 beforehand?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, You don't need to do that.
You can go ahead and install only the latest version.

Pro tip: to manage CyanogenMod updates, you can use an app called [GooManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.s0up.goomanager).

Comment: CyanogenMod has a built in updater now so GooManager is not needed. (Nothing stopping you from using it though)

Comment: @bmdixon True, But I have always found that kind of buggy on my nexus 4. The download speed is also pretty bad on it compared to Goomanager.
That's why I use it instead.